# Magento 2.1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null

Tags: javascript, backend, jquery, magento-2.1

Hi whenever I try to create a new product I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
```

This is the only time I get this, I can create pages, blocks etc. But not the products. It looks like It doesn't generate the static-content correctly for some reason.

I'm running my installation on Forge with nginx, php7.0 and mysql5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1 and Ubuntu 16.04.

The full error log is:

```
import-handler.js:140 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of nullupdateValue @ import-handler.js:140handleNameChanges @ import-handler.js:37setNested @ objects.js:43nested @ objects.js:117set @ element.js:301updateValue @ links.js:57setLink @ links.js:144(anonymous function) @ links.js:165_resolveRequest @ registry.js:413_addRequest @ registry.js:380get @ registry.js:224transfer @ links.js:162setLinks @ links.js:205initLinks @ element.js:182initialize @ element.js:103(anonymous function) @ wrapper.js:109_super @ wrapper.js:106initialize @ abstract.js:69(anonymous function) @ wrapper.js:109UiClass @ class.js:49initComponent @ layout.js:66fire @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @ jquery.js:3211deferred.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:3301fire @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @ jquery.js:3211deferred.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:3301(anonymous function) @ layout.js:59execCb @ 4cdbbd4….js:1650context.execCb @ resolver.js:131check @ 4cdbbd4….js:866(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1113(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:132(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1156each @ 4cdbbd4….js:57emit @ 4cdbbd4….js:1155check @ 4cdbbd4….js:917(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1113(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:132(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1156each @ 4cdbbd4….js:57emit @ 4cdbbd4….js:1155check @ 4cdbbd4….js:917(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1113(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:132(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1156each @ 4cdbbd4….js:57emit @ 4cdbbd4….js:1155check @ 4cdbbd4….js:917enable @ 4cdbbd4….js:1143init @ 4cdbbd4….js:774(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:991(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:132(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:2173execCb @ 4cdbbd4….js:1650context.execCb @ resolver.js:131check @ 4cdbbd4….js:866(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1113(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:132(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1156each @ 4cdbbd4….js:57emit @ 4cdbbd4….js:1155check @ 4cdbbd4….js:917(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1113(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:132(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1156each @ 4cdbbd4….js:57emit @ 4cdbbd4….js:1155check @ 4cdbbd4….js:917(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1113(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:132(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1156each @ 4cdbbd4….js:57emit @ 4cdbbd4….js:1155check @ 4cdbbd4….js:917enable @ 4cdbbd4….js:1143init @ 4cdbbd4….js:774(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:991(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:132(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:2173execCb @ 4cdbbd4….js:1650context.execCb @ resolver.js:131check @ 4cdbbd4….js:866(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1113(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:132(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1156each @ 4cdbbd4….js:57emit @ 4cdbbd4….js:1155check @ 4cdbbd4….js:917(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1113(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:132(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1156each @ 4cdbbd4….js:57emit @ 4cdbbd4….js:1155check @ 4cdbbd4….js:917enable @ 4cdbbd4….js:1143init @ 4cdbbd4….js:774(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:991(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:132(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:2173execCb @ 4cdbbd4….js:1650context.execCb @ resolver.js:131check @ 4cdbbd4….js:866(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1113(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:132(anonymous function) @ 4cdbbd4….js:1156each @ 4cdbbd4….js:57emit @ 4cdbbd4….js:1155check @ 4cdbbd4….js:917enable @ 4cdbbd4….js:1143init @ 4cdbbd4….js:774callGetModule @ 4cdbbd4….js:1170completeLoad @ 4cdbbd4….js:1544onScriptLoad @ 4cdbbd4….js:1671
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been logged with the Magento core team:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5618

Temporary solution:

In the Admin panel navigate to:

**Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Product** Fields Auto-generation.

Set the value of "Mask for SKU" to {{sku}}, save changes and refresh the cache. The Add product page will now load without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly I ran into this issue again after not seeing in for 8 months. Running Magento 2.1.7 currently.

Lance's answer worked for me but I had to also update **Mask for Meta Keywords** to "{{name}}" or "{{sku}}" for this to work.

Another solution is changing `var str = this.mask,` to `var str = this.mask || '',` in file `Magento_Catalog::view/adminhtml/web/js/components/import-handler.js:126`. This was previously fixed and I think a recent magento update broke it again for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I found that **cost** attribute from **advanced pricing** is **required**.

Choose Advanced Pricing  --> cost and set any value then the save button will be functional.